# macbook apache server is always reachable with ip

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, macbook-pro, raspberry-pi

I have a very weird problem going on here. I have a macbook where I have apache php etc installed on. Now every time I got to my IP adress ( extern ) I get to see my files. This is not just annoying but also causes problems because I can't port forward my raspberry pi so that its reachable out of my own network.

I have tried to find out what is causing this but I really don't have a clue. I have a thomson technicolor router from my ISP and I just removed/turned of all the ip forwards and triggers. but I still get the server

I have tried to put the raspberry on 8080 this worked from my own network but not outside of it. and now I just made gave both my mac and raspberry the 80 default.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you port forwarded to your macbook?
Please check your router settings on something like applications.
If possible, give us your router brand and type so i can have a look where it is.

Comment: My router is a Thomson technicolor I have port forwarded to the ip of the raspberry 192.168.0.10 the ip of my macbook is 192.168.0.17

Comment: Did you tried turning your macbook off?

Comment: Yes I did but then I don't get anything

Comment: Do you have multiple routers or something?

Comment: Nope i have only 1 router the one i got from my ISP

Comment: Do they have dynamic ip's or static?
Anything about firewalls we need to know?

Comment: No firewalls and there are dynamic ips'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9300/discussion-between-reshad-and-christiaan-de-die)